# Django comments in shell

Tags: django, django-comments, django-shell

I'm having trouble pulling comments into my template using django comments. I'd like to test some things out in the shell - ie. pulling in an object and getting the set of comments for it - but I'm not sure how to do that.

Is there away to access a model's comments in the shell?

Comment: Actually nevermind - I just noticed the Comment model defined in django.contrib.comments. Silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
python manage.py shell
from django.contrib.comments import Comment

c = Comment.objects.filter(...)

...
```